# How to replace string with its start and end position

Tags: javascript

I have string like `"Hello Bill Gates"` and I have a function which return name position for example if string is `"Hello Bill Gates"` then it will track name from database and return 7 as start point and 16 as end point now what I want is if someone press `BACKSPACE` after `Bill Gates` I get this positions and I want to remove full `Gates` from string and if someone press `BACKSPACE` after `Bill` then it should remove full `Bill`

Its just like facebook tags if you try to remove tag it will remove your first/last name only first.

so can we remove first / last name from positions ?

What I have tried is :

```
$(document).keyup(function(){
$('.string').val().length;
var string = $('.string').val().replace('Bill Gates',$('.string').val().split(' ')[0]);
});
```

Comment: need to do it in javascript

Comment: mentioned jquery is working? and u want the same in javascript?

Comment: Sorry! My bad! JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: its fine if its javascript or jquery or angular but strpos is php function right ?

Comment: have you tried this? `your_string.slice(0, position) + your_string.slice( pos+word_length, your_string.length);` should return string without the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var words = $('.string').val().split(' ');
delete words[words.length - 1];
$('.string').val(words.join(''));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for any strings on your page:

```
$('.element span').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().replace($(this).text().substr(0,$(this).text().indexOf(' ')), '');
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

It removes first word from string and replaces text with rest of string.

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vikrant29/ZSXb6/625/)

Comment: @BillGates, is it helpful?